# Plotting a contour on a surface

Tags: plotting

I can plot the graph of a 3D function and the solution of an equation like in the following example:

```
Fi[x_, y_] := -x^2 - 2*y^2 + 3;
Fj[x_, y_] := -2*(x - 2)^2 - (y - 1)^2 + 4;

Plot3D[{Fi[x, y] - Fj[x, y]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
ContourPlot[{Fi[x, y] - Fj[x, y] == 0}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

How can I combine these plots and plot the solution of the equation on the surface of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Plot3D[{Fi[x, y] - Fj[x, y]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Mesh -> {{0}},MeshFunctions -> (#3 &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You. Is there a way to keep the Mesh and Plot the equation independently? What does `#3` do in this case?

Comment: You want to plot the meshline as a 3D-curve?

Comment: No. I want to keep the Mesh as it was before and add the line of the equation on top of that.

Comment: Ok, just combine the two plots `Show[{Plot3D["mesh as before"],Plot3D["contourline"] }]`